# Component mounts before previous component unmounts ( and keeps the subscription )

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I have two basic components that share a layout. The first one is a list of entries. When the user clicks on "Edit", he is taken to the details page.

The problem is the details page is showing the first record from the "list" page instead of the one the user clicked.

I did some testing and it looks like the issue is the details page is being loaded and mounted before ComponentWIllUnmount() runs so the subscription from that previous page is still active for a few milliseconds. If I visit directly the details page or reload it, it works correctly as it isn't getting any data from the previous page.

Here's my code:

List.jsx

```
export default class List extends TrackerReact( React.Component ) {

    constructor( props ) {

        super( props );

        var subscription = this.getSubscription();

        this.state = {

            ready: subscription.ready(),
            subscription: subscription,

        }

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

        this.state.subscription.stop();

    }

    render() {
        return(
        //stuff...
        )
    }

}
```

Detail.jsx

```
export default class SkinDetail extends TrackerReact( React.Component ) {

    constructor( props ) {

        super( props );

        const subscription = Meteor.subscribe( 'skins.one', this.props.skin );

        var record = Records.findOne();

        if( record ) {

            this.state = {

                subscription: subscription,
                // Stuff...

            }

        }

    }

    getRecord() {

        return Records.findOne();

    }

    render() {

        var record = this.getRecord(); 

        return(
            // Do stuff with record...
        )

    }
}
```

I'm using FlowRouter SSR for the links and routes.

Comment: Don't count on the record being the only one available. Find it by `_id`. Stopping a subscription takes a bit of time (the server needs to let the client know what to remove, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should find your record explicitly, do not rely on the data sent from server.

For example if requirements change and you need to add another component on the detail page showing another record, just using `Records.findOne` will not give you the record you need.

Instead you should provide a query, `_id` for example, to `.find` to get the record. You could define your route with [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#routes-definition) to store the `_id` value: `FlowRouter.route('/details/:_id, {...})`